# Planned comparisons with ridge regression

Tags: r, regression, paired-data

I have a data set that consists of 1 response variables (e.g., response time) and 20-30 predictors variables with a mixture of categorical and continuous data. I code the categorical data into dummy variables, split the data into training and test sets, then perform a ridge regression on the training set:

```
fit.ridge <- glmnet(x.train, y.train, family="gaussian", alpha=0)
```

I was curious how I could go about doing planned comparisons with this fit. I tried generating a model with anova by offsetting coefficients input into a model:

For coefficients in coef(fit.ridge), offset in anova

```
$opt_coef
                                coef      abscoef r_squared
epoch                  -4.428626e-09 4.428626e-09  0.874085
request_length          2.665573e-07 2.665573e-07  0.874085
PUT.tot_count          -3.965862e-06 3.965862e-06  0.874085
stage02.init            1.882785e-04 1.882785e-04  0.874085
upstream10.131.170.102 -2.551089e-04 2.551089e-04  0.874085
PUT.role_count          3.996994e-04 3.996994e-04  0.874085
stage06.2ndreclaim      5.491315e-04 5.491315e-04  0.874085
PUT.upstream_count     -6.168589e-04 6.168589e-04  0.874085
PUT.client_count        1.197713e-03 1.197713e-03  0.874085
stage05.2ndrun          2.124676e-03 2.124676e-03  0.874085
stage04.reclaim        -2.316906e-03 2.316906e-03  0.874085
stage03.delete         -3.258289e-03 3.258289e-03  0.874085
upstream10.131.170.103 -5.956466e-03 5.956466e-03  0.874085
upstream10.131.170.104 -1.578803e-02 1.578803e-02  0.874085
rolebta                 1.736442e-02 1.736442e-02  0.874085
rolebpe                 2.324909e-02 2.324909e-02  0.874085
rolebpt                -2.943251e-02 2.943251e-02  0.874085
rolemmw                -3.597777e-02 3.597777e-02  0.874085
rolebdr                -4.376095e-02 4.376095e-02  0.874085
rolefti                -4.913617e-02 4.913617e-02  0.874085
rolebez                -7.276036e-02 7.276036e-02  0.874085
rolebed                -7.697812e-02 7.697812e-02  0.874085
rolebpp                 8.460213e-02 8.460213e-02  0.874085
rolefts                 1.461163e-01 1.461163e-01  0.874085
(Intercept)             6.944585e+03 6.944585e+03  0.874085

a1 <- aov(formula = response_variable ~ 1 + (coef_var1 * var1) + (coef_var2 * var2) ... )
```

Then calculate a comparison for a predictor variable:

```
TukeyHSD(a1, "var2")
```

However, I'm running into some issues when I try to generate the Tukey test:

```
> a1 <- aov(rt ~ 1 + offset(-4.428626e-09 * epoch) + rolebta, data=data)
> summary(a1)
              Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
rolebta        1   0.56  0.5597   16.38 5.25e-05 ***
Residuals   7324 250.30  0.0342                     
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
> TukeyHSD(a1, "rolebta")
Error in TukeyHSD.aov(a1, "rolebta") : no factors in the fitted model
In addition: Warning message:
In replications(paste("~", xx), data = mf) : non-factors ignored: rolebta
> TukeyHSD(a1, data$rolebta)
Error in TukeyHSD.aov(a1, data$rolebta) : no factors in the fitted model
In addition: Warning message:
In replications(paste("~", xx), data = mf) : non-factors ignored: rolebta
```

Reason I'm trying to do it this way, as opposed to say a pairwise.t.test(), is because I'd like to account for any variance that is not contributed to my predictor of interest. So in the above example, we are correcting for the variable "epoch" before we do the planned contrasts on the "rolebta" factor

I feel like I'm missing something obvious, would someone help me figure out what I've overlooked?

M

Comment: I don't know about how offsets can know about uncertainties.  A bigger problem is that in the frequentist world we lose statistical inference capabilities upon penalization.  For example, a confidence interval for a purposefully shrunken parameter estimate is not well defined.  With Bayesian modeling, shrinkage priors give rise to ordinary posterior distributions so inference is as always.

Comment: You'll have to forgive my lack of understanding, this is largely novel to me. I'm learning, so that's good in theory. So you're suggesting to fit a Bayes linear model. I assume I could do so with something like https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/Bolstad/versions/0.2-40/topics/bayes.lm. Im curious though, does the normal implementation of Bayes lm provide this shrinkage of prior probabilities? I understand that I have to do some deep digging on this, I'm just seeing if I understand the high level picture of this.

Comment: About uncertainties, I thought the coefficients when used as offsets in lm would essentially account for a certain percentage of the error observed in the data, and that the remaining term which had no offset would be available for an anova contrast. So in that sense whatever remaining uncertainty in the model could in theory be accounted for by that variable more or less depending on the R estimates. Again I know I'm over my head in a lot of ways, so if you wouldn't mind pointing me in the right direction, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: I've considered simply doing paired t-tests on the response variable, however it tends to generate clusters which are more or less correlated with a variety of these predictors. I've done some work to elucidate the clusters, and I seem to have a good grasp of what I'm looking at, so perhaps it is apprioriate to perform t-tests when grouping by various predictors. My main concern with this approach is with multiple testing corrections as I'll probably be generating a good number of tests.

Comment: Ultimately, regardless of which approach I take, my main concerns with this data are overfitting and multiple testing corrections. Any ideas are appreciated. Thanks responding, btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regularized regression methods like lasso & ridge regression are meant for training a set of coefficients that is able to predict individual data points as good as possible. Importantly, these methods aim at optimizing predictive performance in "out-of-sample" data, i.e. data points not used in training the coefficients. The very purpose of regularization is to bias these coefficients towards zero in order to get a better predictive performance for individual data points. This makes regularized regression methods sub-optimal for inferential purposes. See [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34469597/what-is-the-difference-between-inferential-analysis-and-predictive-analysis) on the difference between predictive and inferential statistics.

In case you research goal is to interpret your coefficients, you may resort to regular regression. For the concern of over-fitting, given a small-sample size with a large number of potential predictors, I see two established solutions:

1. Conclude that your inferences are exploratory (meant for guiding follow-up research, not making conclusions about the phenomenon in question). You may pre-select predictors based on theory, but you should say that you did so when reporting your results.
2. Get more data, or even better a separate validation sample, to test the robustness of your initial model.

Comment: Ok thanks for the clarification. It helped me to understand Frank's answer as well with respect to Bayesian models with shrinkage priors.